# How to use filter in nested aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

How Can I multiple fields filter from nested object for elasticsearch?

Now I can only do one field filter for elasticsearch nested object.

POST /blog/blog/1

```
{
  "title": "Invest Money",
  "body": "Please start investing money as soon...",
  "tags": ["money", "invest"],
  "published_on": "18 Oct 2017",
  "comments": [
    {
      "name": "William",
      "age": 34,
      "rating": 8,
      "comment": "Nice article..",
      "commented_on": "30 Nov 2017"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 38,
      "rating": 9,
      "comment": "I started investing after reading this.",
      "commented_on": "25 Nov 2017"
    },
    {
      "name": "Smith",
      "age": 33,
      "rating": 7,
      "comment": "Very good post",
      "commented_on": "20 Nov 2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

POST /blog/blog/2

```
{
  "title": "Hero",
  "body": "Hero test body...",
  "tags": ["Heros", "happy"],
  "published_on": "6 Oct 2018",
  "comments": [
    {
      "name": "steve",
      "age": 24,
      "rating": 18,
      "comment": "Nice article..",
      "commented_on": "3 Nov 2018"
    }
  ]
}
```

ES Query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "comments": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "comments"
            },

            "aggs": {
                "groups": {

                    "terms": {
                        "field": "comments.name",
"include": "William",
                        "order": {
                            "rate": "desc"
                        }
                    },

                    "aggs": {
                        "rate": {
                            "min": {
                                "field": "comments.age"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the min age aggregation for each one who made comment. The comments author I can include/exclude the comments.name. I want to add filter for the comments which rating was below 8. Who can help me out to get the dsl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make use of [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to filter the comments based on rating.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "comments": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "comments"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filterByRating": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "comments.rating": {
                "lt": 8
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "groups": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "comments.name",
                "include": "William",
                "order": {
                  "rate": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "rate": {
                  "min": {
                    "field": "comments.age"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```